# How can I make sure a cookie is set before using it?

Tags: typescript, cookies, next.js, jwt, nestjs

I'm currently working on a JWT authorization code flow using Next.js and NestJS.

This is the POST request I'm sending from the front to the back.

```js
const response = await fetch(
  'http://localhost:4000/auth/42/callback?code=' + code, { // code is received from the OAuth server
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'include',
  }
);
```

Once the backend receives the request, it will generate the JWT and send it back to the front using `response`.

```js
@Post('42/callback')
async Callback(@Query('code') code: string, @Res({passthrough: true}) res) {
  if (!code) {
    res.status(400).send('Missing code');
    return;
  }

  try {
    const response = await this.authService.exchangeCodeForToken(code);
    const jwt = await this.authService.handleCallback(response);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.cookie('jwt', jwt, {
      sameSite: 'strict'
    });
    res.status(200).send();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
  }
}
```

The browser successfully sets the `jwt` cookie, however I'm unable to find a way to make sure it is set before using it.
It seems that there is a small latency between the response and setting the cookie.

```js
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

const [ cookies ] = useCookies();

const jwt = cookies.jwt;
const jwtPayload: any = jwtDecode(jwt); // Here jwt is undefined
```

I've looked at the browser Network Profiler but I'm not able to see any latency.
[image: Browser network profiler]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution to my problem.
Apparently, `react-cookie` is not reliable in some situations (see this [issue](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/issues/304) or this [one](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/issues/281)). The `useCookies` hook is not updating when a new cookie is added. While this issue isn't fixed the best workaround is to use [universal-cookie](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie#readme) instead.

Here is what it will looks like:

```js
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

const cookies = new Cookies();
const jwt = cookies.get('jwt');
const decodedPayload = jwtDecode(jwt);
```

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the delay and to ensure that you access the cookie value only after it has been set, you can use the useEffect hook. Something like this..

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie'

function YourComponent() {
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies()
  const jwt = cookies.jwt

  useEffect(() => {
    if (jwt) {
      const jwtPayload: any = jwtDecode(jwt);
      // Access the jwtPayload or perform any other actions with the JWT here
    }
  }, [jwt])

  // Rest of your component code

  return <div>Your component content</div>
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Alternatively you can also create a custom hook if you prefer. something like this...

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie'

function useJWT() {
  const [cookies] = useCookies()
  const [jwt, setJWT] = useState(null)
  const [jwtPayload, setJWTPayload] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cookies.jwt) {
      setJWT(cookies.jwt)
    }
  }, [cookies.jwt])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (jwt) {
      const decodedPayload = jwtDecode(jwt)
      setJWTPayload(decodedPayload);
    } else {
      setJWTPayload(null)
    }
  }, [jwt])

  return jwtPayload
}

export default useJWT
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, unfortunately it didn't fix the problem. It seems that there is a problem with react-cookie. You can read my answer for more informations